# What if .NET framework is not available

Tags: c#, .net

I have searched a lot about this, but didn't get any understandable answer. May be I didn't search with right words.

**The Question is:**
If I create an exe in c# and the computer on which I am going to run it doesn't have .NET Framework, How am I suppose to run that exe on that computer?

Is there any way I can check the .NET Framework first and silently install the required version?

Comment: if it has windows vista or 7 it has .net 2 and 3 pre installed http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/34b148f6-539e-4d73-9d67-0a02ad87923d/which-net-framework-version-is-installed-by-default-automatically-with-the-basic-installation-of

Comment: yes but if windows xp or earlier is there then what? :)
Plus windows 8 only supports .NET 4.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 has Setup & Deployment Project (at least Professional Edition + does... i cannot say for certain on other editions).  This will include prerequisites such as the .NET framework version that your app requires.

**Edit**

There is no "work-around".  The very notion of "silently installing dependencies" is a setup program.  Otherwise you'll need to instruct consumers of your .exe to go and download the framework themselves, or run another exe prior to running your app.

*You're trying to avoid using an installer then asking how to run an app without using an installer*.

Comment: I am talking about an exe here. I don't want to create a setup for my project.

Comment: The setup project creates an exe.  You need to have the prerequisites somewhere and there's no such thing as "silently" installing the prerequisites without some notion of a setup program.

Comment: hmm Thank you Moo-Juice :)
I think I should create the setup project rather than standalone exe.

Comment: @SyedRizwanAli, it's quite straight-forward.  Just add the Setup project to the solution of your application.  It will take the primary output of your other project and figure out the dependencies and build an installer for you.  No effort involved in your behalf unless you need to do something esoteric.

Answer (score 1):

If computer doesn't have .net framework installed, user will get error message on application start (Don't remember exact text)

You can always check Which version's of framework exists on machine, and run the installer if necessary

Just check this registery key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are some more details

While creating setup, you can set .net framework as an pre-requirement and installer will care to install framework if does not exist

You can find more details about [.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#chaining_redistributable)

Answer (score 1):

I see no example answer for this question. So here is an example that will check if a user has .NET Framework 4.5 or higher then prompt them to download:

```
//.. your code
// Calling function inside Load event
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //call function
        Get45PlusFromRegistry();
    }
//Functions
        private static void Get45PlusFromRegistry()
        {
            const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";

            using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
            {
                if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null)
                {
                    //Do nothing if .Net 4.5 or higher is found.
                    //MessageBox.Show(".NET Framework Version: " + CheckFor45PlusVersion((int)ndpKey.GetValue("Release")));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do something if .Net 4.5 or higher is found
                    MessageBox.Show("This program Requires .NET Framework Version 4.5 or later. Click OK to access Microsoft official website and download .NET 4.5 framework.");
                    Process.Start(@"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653");
                }
            }
        }

        // Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility.
        private static string CheckFor45PlusVersion(int releaseKey)
        {
            if (releaseKey >= 461808)
                return "4.7.2 or later";
            if (releaseKey >= 461308)
                return "4.7.1";
            if (releaseKey >= 460798)
                return "4.7";
            if (releaseKey >= 394802)
                return "4.6.2";
            if (releaseKey >= 394254)
                return "4.6.1";
            if (releaseKey >= 393295)
                return "4.6";
            if (releaseKey >= 379893)
                return "4.5.2";
            if (releaseKey >= 378675)
                return "4.5.1";
            if (releaseKey >= 378389)
                return "4.5";
            // This code should never execute. A non-null release key should mean
            // that 4.5 or later is installed.
            return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
        }
//..your code
```

Source: [Microsoft Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the .NET Framework contain the dlls and the functions you used in dev then you must install it

you have to read about .NET Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w.aspx

the workaround is to make an installtion to check if exist

Answer (score 0):

there is no hidden way to install .NET framework you can include .net framework with your exe or application setup. So if .net framework on required machine is not found it will be installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply if the computer doesn't have the required .NET version, a popup msgbox with "Stop" image tells you that the app needs to have .NET xxx installed , and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY want to run it without .NET Framework, you can use some software to package every dependency in one single file without need to install it.

There are a lot of them, I know for example [Spoon Studio](http://spoon.net/studio)

I really discourage the usage of those, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to add .Net Framework if you are running in window XP. In window 7 .Net Framework already install you can run without any installation

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2012 and later you can create a InstalShield LE installer

Then under '2. Specify Application Data' > 'Redistributables' select the Full version of the .NET framwork you wish to deploy i.e. 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full' (I suggest the web download as .NET is several hundred Mb)

Under '5. Define Setup Requirements and Actions' > 'Requirements' select requirements and check the required .NET framework.

When the installer is run the user will be told .NET is required and to click OK (or something along these lines, i forget exactly) to install .NET.