# C# publish application by using copy and paste only

Tags: c#, .net, copy-paste, messagebox

I have a problem when publish application using copy and paste directly on user machine I face very bad error message appear when .NET Framework is not installed on user computer.

To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
v4.0.30319
Contact your application publisher for instruction about obtaining the appropriate version of the .NET Framework.

My question is:

When user click on application icon 
I want to display custom message box tell user to use .NET Framework
if not installed on user machine.

Comment: This is called **prerequisites**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Check If The .Net Framework Is Installed \[C# / WPF\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945006/how-to-check-if-the-net-framework-is-installed-c-wpf)

Comment: @Jim - can you elaborate on that. Are you referring to a general notion, or a technical solution to this problem?

Comment: @mmcrae The actual question is: *when user click on application icon i want to display custom message box tell user to use .net frame work if not installed on user machine* so i do refer to the whole topic.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a wrapper application which, when clicked, will check if the .NET framework exists. If it does, run the app. Otherwise, show the error message.

But now this wrapper applications needs to reliably run on the platform, even if there is no C#/.NET version which you are checking for.

Comment: The problem is also discussed here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945006/how-to-check-if-the-net-framework-is-installed-c-wpf

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850756/what-if-net-framework-is-not-available

Comment: May be one of these deployment options will inspire you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The check for framework version needs to be outside C# in case there is no suitable Net Framework installed. There are lot of Powershell scripts which do this check, but they are not always portable. This link has a VBS script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147427/detect-net-framework-3-5-or-higher-using-vbs-through-wmi